Transfering NaN's to Dummy Variables While Using One Hot Encoder
I am using OneHotEncoder to create a series of dummy variables based on a categoric variable.  The problem I encounter is that any missing values are not transfered to the available dummy variables.
oh = OneHotEncoder(min_frequency = 0.0001, sparse_output = False) ### df_experience_level
data = oh.fit_transform(df[['experience_level']])
cols=oh.get_feature_names_out()
df_experience_level = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)

missing_values_count = df_experience_level.isnull().sum()
missing_values_count

output:
experience_level_EN     0
experience_level_EX     0
experience_level_MI     0
experience_level_SE     0
experience_level_nan    0
dtype: int64

The current code that I use is:
df.loc[df['experience_level'].isna(), 'experience_level_EN'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['experience_level'].isna(), 'experience_level_EX'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['experience_level'].isna(), 'experience_level_MI'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['experience_level'].isna(), 'experience_level_SE'] = np.nan

However this is tedious.
Running the obvious:
df.loc[df['experience_level'].isna(), df_experience_level] = np.nan

Results in:
ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional

Is there any way to transfer the NaNs from the parent variable to each dummy variable in a single statement?

You can try with str.startswith to select the correct column subset:
# Obviously replace exp_lvl with experience_level
subset = df_exp_lvl.columns.str.startswith('exp_lvl')
df_exp_lvl.loc[df['exp_lvl'].isna(), subset] = np.nan

Output:
>>> df_exp_lvl
    exp_lvl_EN  exp_lvl_EX  exp_lvl_MI  exp_lvl_SE  exp_lvl_nan
0          1.0         0.0         0.0         0.0          0.0
1          0.0         0.0         1.0         0.0          0.0
2          1.0         0.0         0.0         0.0          0.0
3          1.0         0.0         0.0         0.0          0.0
4          0.0         0.0         0.0         1.0          0.0
5          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
6          0.0         1.0         0.0         0.0          0.0
7          0.0         1.0         0.0         0.0          0.0
8          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
9          0.0         0.0         0.0         1.0          0.0
10         0.0         0.0         1.0         0.0          0.0
11         0.0         0.0         1.0         0.0          0.0
12         1.0         0.0         0.0         0.0          0.0
13         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
14         0.0         1.0         0.0         0.0          0.0

>>> df
   exp_lvl
0       EN
1       MI
2       EN
3       EN
4       SE
5      NaN
6       EX
7       EX
8      NaN
9       SE
10      MI
11      MI
12      EN
13     NaN
14      EX

